# Is there a more robust rename alternative than select with triple exclamation mark?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following simplified use-case and it fails, stating that a column isn't there, which is correct. In my real use-case, this tibble comes from parsing an XML, which may not include all the expected columns but a subset in a few cases, i.e., missing values:

```
library(tidyverse)
mapping <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
names(mapping) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')

tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c('m', 'm', 'm')) %>%
  select(!!! mapping)
Error: Unknown column `c` 
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The error is correct. However, is there a way to robustify this so that `c` would be created with NAs automatically when missing?

**UPDATE:** I worked out the following simple solution outside tidyverse:

```
# create a data frame instead of a tibble
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c('m', 'm', 'm'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# fill in missing columns with NAs
df[,setdiff(mapping, colnames(df))] <- NA
# reorder columns to match the mapping
df <- df[, mapping]
df
# now is safe to rename using the mapping
as_tibble(df) %>%
   select(!!! mapping)
```

I'm still interested in a modern solution using `tidyverse` and `tibble`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension to your solution could be

```
library(tidyverse)

df[,setdiff(mapping, colnames(df))] <- NA

df %>% rename_all(~names(mapping))

#  x y  z
#1 1 m NA
#2 2 m NA
#3 3 m NA
```

---

Or another approach

```
map_dfc(setdiff(mapping, colnames(df)), ~df %>% mutate(!!.x := NA)) %>%
    arrange(mapping) %>%
    rename_all(~names(mapping))
```

Comment: Thank you but I need `c` column with `NA`s not simply excluding it ... besides I don't see the renaming happening either :(

Comment: @SkyWalker Added couple of options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I designed that may suit your needs. `dat` is the data frame you want to select columns. `mapping` is a vector contains the column names you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

select_fun <- function(dat, mapping){
  cols_same <- intersect(names(dat), mapping)
  cols_different <- setdiff(mapping, names(dat))

  if (length(cols_same) > 0){
    dat2 <- dat %>% 
      select(cols_same) %>%
      set_names(names(mapping[mapping %in% cols_same]))
    if (length(cols_different) > 0){
      for (col in cols_different){
        dat2[[names(mapping[mapping %in% col])]] <- NA
      }
    }
  } else {
    dat2 <- NA
  }
  return(dat2)
}
```

Let's test the function.

Test 1: The original question

```
mapping <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
names(mapping) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
dat <- tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c('m', 'm', 'm'))
select_fun(dat, mapping)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x y     z    
#   <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
# 1     1 m     NA   
# 2     2 m     NA   
# 3     3 m     NA
```

Test 2: `mapping` contains less matching column names than `dat`

```
mapping <- c('a', 'b')
names(mapping) <- c('x', 'y')
dat <- tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c('m', 'm', 'm'), c=c('n', 'n', 'n'))
select_fun(dat, mapping)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       x y    
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 m    
# 2     2 m    
# 3     3 m
```

Test 3: No matches

```
mapping <- c('x', 'y', "z")
names(mapping) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
dat <- tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c('m', 'm', 'm'))
select_fun(dat, mapping)
# [1] NA
```

Notice that I am not sure what do you want if `mapping` and the column names of `dat` have no matches. For now, I set the response of this function to be `NA`. You can easily modify this response by editing the last `else` state. For example, below is a version that the function will return an empty data frame with column names the same as the `dat`.

```
  } else {
    dat2 <- dat %>% slice(0)
  }
```